# PSIM and LTspice Constant On Time Control

Tags: power, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, control

I am trying to control a converter with constant on time. I mean the off-time should be changed with the changing of the output voltage. How can I achieve this? I try many methods with using error amplifier with comparator but I could not achieve. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

For a constant-on-time (COT) converter, you can try my ready-made [template](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) described here which works with the free demo of SIMPLIS, [Elements](https://www.simplistechnologies.com/product/elements). The circuit below shows a compensated buck converter:

[image]

In this mode, the valley current is adjusted to perform a constant-on-time regulation scheme. This is a 5-V/1-A converter switching at 2.2 MHz. If you now step the output, you can see how the on-time remains constant while the off-time depends on the error voltage:

[image]